# Why is Automapper error not including destination details?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper

We have automapper v4.2 which mostly works fine, however every 4-6 weeks we get this weird error when the mapping stops

```
Mapping types:
DynamicContentSearchResultItem -> Full
Models.Messages.Search.DynamicContentSearchResultItem -> Models.Alerts.Views.Client.Full

Destination path:
List`1[0]
```

It doesn't even complain about any specific property, just plainly stops working unless we reset the app pool.

All the mappings are registered and initialized on Application_Start like

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<DynamicContentSearchResultItem, ClientFull>()
                .IncludeBase<DynamicContentSearchResultItem, ClientTraveller>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Assessment, AssessmentTransformer)
                .ForMember(d => d.ManagerAdvice, ManagerAdviceTransformer);
```

and its invoked in the code when the mapping's about to be called after search as

```
var alerts = Mapper.Map<List<InternalFull>>(results, optionsParam).ToList<IArticle>();
```

I would appreciate all help.

thanks

Comment: You should upgrade.

Comment: Hi @LucianBargaoanu, thanks for your input. We will go that route. Oddly, its just that single mapping that starts failing flat, everything else works fine (this endpoint's called the most though). I have not been able to reproduce this locally which makes it rather more frustrating

Comment: It could be a threading issue. And that can be tricky. There are no such issues in the newer versions. At least none that we are aware of :)